# Ajax - send button value to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a problem with send data to php. I want to send button value via jquery ajax. This is my code:
HTML

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "try.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            data: val    // removed ; after val.
        }
    });
});

</script>

    <body>

      <button id="1" name="1"  value="some_value">1</button>
      <button id="2" name="2"  value="some_value">2</button>


    </body>
```

PHP:

```
<?php

$name = $_POST['data'];
echo $name;

?>
```

It doesn't working...

Comment: check your browser console for errors.

Comment: Try console.log for your val to see if it contains the value

Comment: you need to get `$_POST['data']` instead of `$_POST['val']`

Comment: `val` is undefined in your code. You need to actually give the variable a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make proper json string to send data. You are having extra `;` there.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "try.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            data: val    // removed ; after val.
        }
    });
});
```

And get it with `data` key in php.

```
<?php

$name = $_POST['data'];
echo $name;
?>
```

Also, write your event listeners inside `document.ready()`. Currently your listeners are not getting applied as the script is on the top and is not able to find the `<button>` as they are not yet present.

Comment: No, it still doesn't working. 
Nothing happens when I press the button.

Comment: like this?
$(document).ready(function(){
$('button').click(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();

$.ajax({
    url: "try.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        data: val    // removed ; after val.
    }
});
});
});

Comment: yes, @Daro125, I have updated my answer for the same.

Comment: Still nothing :/

Comment: did you check if $_POST['data'] has the value you send from ajax?

Comment: How can I check this?

Comment: `print_r($_POST['data']);die;`

Comment: Can you  put this line `print_r('I reached here');die;`  just before `$name = $_POST['data'];` ?

Comment: I put this line, but nothing is displayed after click button

Comment: check the network tab once you click. the text `I reached here` should be printed on response tab of Network.

Comment: Thank you for your help, it works, I did not know how it should work and that's why I thought it did not work :D

Comment: ok @Daro125, would you accept the answer if you get solution from this? And Up vote too??

Comment: I accept the answer, but I haven't 15 reputation , so my votes isn't displayed.

Answer (score 3):

try this out, i just did and worked fine

here's my js file

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="1" name="1" value="some_value">1</button>
    <button id="2" name="2" value="some_value">2</button>
</body>
<footer>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('button').click(function() {
                var val = $(this).val();
                $.ajax({
                    // your uri, pay attention if the post is going to the right place
                    url: "try.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    // myVar = name of the var that you will be able to call in php
                    // val = your data
                    data: {'myVar': val}
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</footer>
</html>
```

and here's my php

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['myVar']; //the var you put in your ajax data:{}
print_r($name);
```

in google chrome you can press f12 and go to Network Tab, you will be able to see the requisitions that your browser made and theirs responses

Comment: @Daro125 hmm.. that's wierd, the name of your php file is 'try.php'?
also, try this in your javascript, after the line 'var val = $(this).val();' add an 'alert(val);'
and in your php file in the first row you will write print_r(['im here', $_POST]);

Comment: Thank you for your help, it works, I did not know how it should work and that's why I thought it did not work :D

Answer (score 0):

```
<button id="example" name="name_example"  value="some_value">
1</button>

$(document).ready(function () {
     $('#example').click(function() {

         var buttonValue = $(this).val();

         $.ajax({
             url: "try.php", //assuming that your html file is in the same folder as 
                    //your php script. 
              type: "POST",
              data: {'example': buttonValue}
         });

    });
});
```

look this: https://jsfiddle.net/willianoliveirac/yarLfdnu/

In your .php file, which should be in the same folder as your html file doing the request you will have:

```
<?php 

echo '<pre>'; print_r($_POST); die; // see if you now have those vars. 

?>
```